# High Number of MSC Threads

Tags: jboss7.x, redhat

My application id deployed on Jboss 7.1 and I can see 256 "MSC service thread" running and in waiting (parked) state.

What's the reason for so many threads? what do they do? Is it safe to reduce the number? If positive, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in later versions of msc as part of https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MSC-144

you can manually upgrade jboss msc in 7.1.1 or upgrade to WildFly 8.1 that already has msc with this fix.